# Laravel: Get softdeleted row in a query builder consult

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How do I get a row that was sofdeleted for example
This is my code:

```
$mov = $emp->movimientos()->where('movimiento.linea_id', intval($request->id_caso))->with('producto_nombre', 'costo_promedio');
```

I have this consult, one `movimientos` is related with a `costo_promedio`, but if in some case a`costo_promedio` is softdeleted the result in my consult `$mov` will give me null in the part of `costo_promedio`.
The thing is, where do I have to puth the `withTrashed()` method to get all data even the ones that were softdeleted

Thx for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `with()` with a closure:

```
$mov = $emp->movimientos()
    ->where('movimiento.linea_id', intval($request->id_caso))
    ->with([
        'producto_nombre',
        'costo_promedio' => function($query) {
            $query->withTrashed();  
        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can call `withTrashed()` function anywhere in 'Eloquent Query Builder' instance, but before `get()` or `first()` finction.

to eager load relationship with trashed, you can give a closure to the relationship.

```
$mov = $emp->movimientos()->where('movimiento.linea_id', intval($request->id_caso))
    ->with([
        'producto_nombre',
        'costo_promedio' => function($q) {
            $q->withTrashed();  
        }
    ])->get();
```